# What is the meaning of "doch" in these two sentences?

Tags: word-usage

- *Gib mir doch bitte Bescheid*
- *Gib mir doch bitte 200 hundert Gramm von dem weichen Käse*

I think the first *doch* is when you crave that the other person to give a yes for an answer and the second one is the after all type, but I'm not sure. Can someone please explain the meaning of *doch* in each sentence?

Comment: It's in both cases an intensifier for *bitte*, and as you noted correctly, it expresses craving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding *doch* to a sentence can change the meaning in all sorts of different ways dependng on the emphasis

- Gib mir doch bitte Bescheid

can mean either "**do** let me know", or "let me know after all", although the first would be more likely - the kind of thing you'd say to somebody who has a habit of not letting you know. In the second case you could also say "Gib mir bitte doch Bescheid"

It in no way implies your are wanting yes for an answer

- Gib mir doch bitte 200 hundert Gramm von dem weichen Käse

probably means "after all". Although, spoken angrily, it could imply impatience: stop messing around and give me the cheese.

In either example another possibility is that *doch* is being used as a [filler word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)) to soften the directness of the request

Comment: It can also just be a 'filler', to make your request less direct.

Comment: @OliverMason Thank you. I don't think this is the case in either of these  examples, but I've added it as a possibilty

Comment: For me in both cases the 'Modalpartikel' _doch_ is used in order to soften the strictness of the imperatives. See [link] (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel#Bedeutung_einzelner_Modalpartikeln): "Abmilderung eines Imperativs, z. B. in 'geh doch noch einmal zurück!', 'Lies doch noch einmal, was ich dir geschrieben habe' anstatt 'geh noch einmal zurück', 'Lies noch einmal, was ich dir geschrieben habe.' Einer Aufforderung kann durch die Partikel so ihre Schärfe genommen werden."

Comment: @RalfJoerres I still think it all depends on the emphasis and the context. Your examples could also be understood as a hard imperative. Anyway there's already a better answer on GLSE on the use of *doch* as a Modalpartikel. Aber lies doch noch einmal den von dir gelinkten Wikipediaartikel. *Doch* is Polyfunktional und kann auch  Steigerungspartikel, Konjunktionaladverb, koordinierende Konjunktion oder adverbiale Bestimmung sein

Comment: @PiedPiper: Der einzige Kontext, den ich mir vorstellen kann, um aus einem freundlich formulierten Satz eine 'strikte Aufforderung mit hohem Erwartungsdruck' zu machen ist ein großes Autoritätsgefälle zwischen dem Anweisenden und dem Anweisungsempfänger. Typische Beispiele wären Mutter > kleineres Kind; Chef / Abteilungsleiter / Weisungsbefugter > Untergebener. Dazu passen aber die Sätze nicht. Die anderen von Dir genannten Funktionen "Steigerungspartikel ..." kommen ohnehin nicht in Frage. Für eine Abmilderung sprechen auch die beiden 'bitte', in anderen Beispielen zusätzliche '(ein)mal'.

Answer (score 2):

**Doch** is a [Füllwort](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuellwort) here, so according to Duden a *Wort mit geringem Aussagewert*.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCllwort) says:

*Füllwörter [...] dienen dazu, einen Inhalt emotional zu färben oder einen Vers zu glätten. In der gesprochenen Sprache werden Füllwörter zur Verbesserung des Sprachflusses eingesetzt.
In der geschriebenen Sprache sind zu viele Füllwörter außerhalb der wörtlichen Rede überflüssig, da sie einen Text unnötig aufblähen, ohne zur Verständlichkeit beizutragen und ihn dadurch schlechter lesbar machen. Füllwörter tragen aber auch zum Textfluss bei, da ohne sie viele Texte abrupt klingen und ein parataktischer Satzbau entsteht.*

Comment: *Doch* can be used as a filler word, but I don't think that usage fits these examples well

Comment: 'Füllwort' ist ein stilkritisch intendierter Behelfsausdruck für i.d.R. Modalpartikeln. Es gab eine Zeit, da kannte man 'Modalpartikeln' noch nicht: Was bei der Wortartbestimmung auch noch durch die Maschen der Adverb- und Interjektions-Prüfung als letzte Auffangmöglichkeit für unsortierten Kleinkram gerutscht war, konnte dann nur noch 'Füllwort' sein. Ganz nett die Diskussion hierzu in dem verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel. Dass diese Wörter stilistische Probleme schaffen, jedoch auch Texte eingängiger machen können, trifft andererseits zu. Nur ging es bei der Frage hier nicht so sehr um den Stil.